# Fortran error in passing function

Tags: function, fortran

I am trying writing a simple Fortran code that calculates h = g(f(x)). The x is a vector of length=2.

```
module m1
implicit none
contains

function f(x)
implicit none
real::f(2),x(2)
f(1)=x(1)-x(2)
f(2)=exp(x(1))-x(2)**2
end function f

function g(ff)
implicit none
real::g(2),x1(2),ffreslt(2)
interface
    function ff(x)
    implicit none
    real::x(2),ff(2)
    end function ff
end interface
ffreslt=ff(x1)
g(1)=1-ffreslt(1)
g(2)=2*ffreslt(1)**2-3*ffreslt(2)+4.2
end function g

end module m1

program hgf
use m1
implicit none
real::x1(2),h(2)
x1 = (/0.55,2.47/)
h = g(f(x1))

write(*,*) h

end program hgf
```

But, I am getting this error message:

```
h = g(f(x1))
      1
Error: Actual parameter 'ff' at <1> is not a PROCEDURE
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You should pass the function and the `x1` vector separately.

Comment: Note: you don't need to repeat "implicit none" in each subroutine. It's enough to just state it once at the top of the module (the only exception is the interface block, where you need to repeat it).

Answer (score 5):

in the call to g() you are not passing the function f() but rather the result of calling the function f() with the value of x1.

Check this [Notes on converting from F77 to F90](http://www.nccs.nasa.gov/tutorials/f90studentnotes.pdf) and look at page 24, Section 3.2.7.

Also check this question on [procedures as arguments](http://objectmix.com/fortran/304367-procedures-arguments-set-dummy-arguments.html).